# Best practice to design big entities

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

What would be the best practice to design a big entity like an Employee table that contains over 100 attributes?

Should I keep them as a single table with 100 columns or should I split them and to 1..1 relations and then compose the Employee object in my code?

Any opinions? Pros and cons of each method?

Comment: There are many things that can go into a decision like that. The first thing would be to ask *are there really 100 individual attributes that relate to every single employee?*

Comment: It really depends on what you'll be using the info for, how often you will be updating the information, how you will be consuming the information, etc.

If you're doing some data warehousing, it is perfectly fine to have 100s of columns in a table. More traditional transactional systems might give issues with such an approach, though.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Yes, there really is 100 or so attributes. This table will hold everything for the employee's name, social number to his salary, insurance information. Every employee has this information or will have this information after a certain amount of time.

Comment: @user569711 The information is used in multiple ways. It will be used to store occasional information usage such as "Hired date" but also frequent usage like getting the employee name from his ID or Employee number.

Comment: @Pluc: Salary and insurance information, to pick just two things, often change during the course of a year. And usually, when those things change, a business needs to know not only the current value, but the previous value, too (if not the entire history). That kind of requirement is best implemented in related tables. So, most of us would expect fewer distinct attributes than you'd expect. (Assuming you've correctly eliminated all transitive dependencies in the first place.)

Comment: Salary is actually already a related table. It was a bad example. Insurance doesn't need history. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here lies not in the Employees table, but in the wider database design. If all attributes are definitely 1-1 then I would definitely have one entity. SQL Server has optimizations you can employ when you get to the physical design, such as SPARSE columns for columns that have many NULL values.

I assume you are going through the process of normalization and Entity Relationship Diagrams at the moment. If you are, then I would suggest looking at a SuperType/SubType approach, for which Employees is normally a great candidate.

In this approach (as example) you may have a "Contacts" table, which would contain First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, etc. This would then link to your Employees table, your Customers table, your Vendors table, etc. Your employees table would then just contain the attributes that are unique to Employees, such as Staff Number, Start Date, etc.

There are several benefits to this.

- Firstly, if an employee is also a customer, for example, then you reduce data redundancy.
- You are likely to achieve a better compression ratio. This is because when you have fewer columns, there will be more rows stored on a page, meaning the name "Smith" will appear on the same page more often.
- From a Master Data perspective, if a company standard for data type of an email column is introduced, then you can change it in one place, not three places. (Forgive the slightly contrived example here but hopefully it illustrates the point).
- As both the Super Table and the Sub Table have fewer columns, each can be read faster in isolation. If joined in the same query, and placed on separate Discs then the 2 tables can be read in parallel.

Comment: I considered this approach (without knowning it was called SuperType / Subtype) but I'm unsure of what the benefits would be. The Contact entities would only be used in a single employee instance. I would never use the ID of the Contact table to keep a reference to a employee's contact name because there will be more information I would be interested in (for exemple, a cost system that wants to know the salary of the employee to calculate the value of his invested time). It feels like a useless strugle and I fail to see the advantages.

Comment: @Pluc: The point of a super/subtype relationship is very similar to the concept of inheritance (or LSP) in OO design; that is, in Pete's example, every `Employee` is a `Contact`, but presumably there are other `Contact` records that are *not* `Employee`s. This is useful and beneficial by allowing you to store common attributes in one table, then create simple related tables that store information specific to other types. The alternatives would either be to duplicate these attributes in all tables or use one giant table with lots of nulls.

Comment: (cont.) If you don't have this sort of relationship, though, then this particular approach is not well-suited to your problem.

Comment: Agree with Adam. I have also updated my answer with some further benefits

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did accept this answer as it is the correct one, but I will most-likely not apply this approach because the benifits does not apply to my circumstances. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try and read up on Star-Schema and Snowflake-Schema. These are terms used when it comes to designing data warehousing schemas, and the pros and cons probably are very similar to what you are facing here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema

http://www.diffen.com/difference/Snowflake_Schema_vs_Star_Schema